# Automatic redirection from http to https with .htaccess authentication in virtual hosting

Tags: htaccess, redirects, https, apache2, virtualhost

Hi I have configured Virtual host on apache with *.htaccess* authentication with SSL. It's working fine when I typed url `https://www.example.com:9004/test.php` but when I typed `http://www.example.com:9004/test.php` I am getting this error:

```
Bad Request

Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Reason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port.
Instead use the HTTPS scheme to access this URL, please.
Hint: https://www.example.com/
```

My *httpd.conf* file look like this:

```
 Listen 9004
<VirtualHost *:9004>
    ServerAdmin root@localhost
    DocumentRoot /mnt/work/httpd
    <Directory "/mnt/work/httpd">
    Options FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride AuthConfig
    </Directory>
  SSLEngine On
  SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /mnt/work/httpd/www.example.com.key
  SSLCertificateFile /mnt/work/httpd/www.example.com.crt
#RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com:9006%{REQUEST_URI}
    ServerName www.example.com
    ErrorLog "/mnt/work/log/error_log"
    CustomLog "/mnt/work/log/access_log" combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And my */etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf* file is:

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so

#
# When we also provide SSL we have to listen to the
# the HTTPS port in addition.
#
Listen 9006
```

And Mmy *.htaccess* file is:

```
AuthType Digest
AuthName "Protected"
AuthDigestProvider file
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthUserFile /mnt/work/httpd/digest_auth
Require user johan
```

What should I do so that when I hit `http:/www.example.com:9004/test.php` it will automatically redirect to `https://www.example.com:9004/test.php`.

Answer (score 3):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: Hi Its not Working Same error Occurred  Bad Request...

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want 9004 for https; 9006 for http; You should redirect http connection on 9004 port to https connection on same 9004 port.

However your config redirects http://example.com:9004 to https://example.com:9006 which does not make much sense since 9006 port is for http. Just replace 9006 by 9004 in your RewriteRule.

Some additional info on url redirection: http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RedirectSSL